# How to check if this month is the month we are in for calendar purpose

Tags: javascript, date, calendar

I am making a calendar and I am coloring today's date in different color, just like any other calendar, but when I click on next button to show next month, It makes that months 18th date also in different color, It should not doing that unless that is really that month we are in. e.g window calendar when we click on next arrow it will show the next month and it will not show any colored date, because that month we are not in, how can I achieve that in my code, I hope I have explain it well.

```
var rowCellIndex = document.getElementById('tableId');

var x = 1;
var i = firstday;

for (var v = 1; v <= totalRows; v++) {

    for (var y = i; y < totalTds; y++) {

        rowCellIndex.rows[v].cells[y].innerHTML = x;   

        if(x == this.getDate){
        rowCellIndex.rows[v].cells[y].style.backgroundColor = '#393939';
        }

        x++;

        if (x > totalDays) {
            break;
        }
    }

    i = 0;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date , fetch month from it

Comment: if teachers are going to recommend their students go to SO for help they should at least give them a primer on how to ask first.

Comment: Youre not highlighting the date, youre highlighting a grid field. If you click on next month, simply reset the grid...

Comment: `this.getDate` is likely a function, not a property. Or maybe that's a typo, but I have not idea what *this* is.

Comment: this.getDate = this.getDate(); this i didn't show because that's not I am worried about